# php convert number into minutes

Tags: php, numbers

Say i have a variable like `$speed = 5.5`, what formula would I use to convert that into minutes, so in this case it would be 5 and a half minutes.

I need it to work in this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$now - $speed mins"));
```

Other examples, 2.25 would convert to 2 mins 15 secs, 7:75 to 7 mins 45 secs, etc

Anyone have any ideas? Never been a maths buff.

Comment: Is the seconds part always going to be something like .25, .50, .75, or .00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do it with second.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(sprintf('- %d second', $speed * 60)));
```

If you want more precision, then

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(sprintf('- %d second', round($speed * 60))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PHP's own DateInterval class (requires PHP 5.3) http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php

With sample:

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('5.5 minutes');
echo $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also a Unix Timestamp for dates and 3600 = 1 hour.

For example, the current time would be: $timestamp = gmmktime();

So if you wanted to add ".5" (30 minutes) to the current time, you would say $timestamp + 1800. ".25" would be $timestamp + 900.

Answer (score 0):

```
$minutes = floor($speed);
$seconds = ($speed - $minutes) * 60;
```